# Displaying Value of register in assembly

Tags: gcc, assembly, printf

I have assembly code that performs a mathematic equation which result is stored in the `ebx` register. How can I display the value of the register? I was thinking of pushing the value of `ebx` to the stack, then `"%i\n"`, and calling printf, but if this would work, I don't know how it could be coded in GCC assembly using MacOS.

Comment: You'll have to tell us what arch:  x86?  x86_64?  PPC?  That will affect both the assembly and the calling convention used to invoke printf.

Comment: I am compiling the assembly using GCC, so it will be linked to libc, if that makes a difference. According to `uname` I am using the i386 architecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f()
{
        asm("movl $42, %ebx");
        asm("movl %ebx, %eax");
}

main() {
        printf("%i\n", f()); // displays 42.
}
```

As you can see, EAX register's content will be used as return value for f() function.